# Getting a list of markers with jQuery/gmap3 when using the Directions service

Tags: google-maps-markers, directions, jquery-gmap3

I started using the gmap3 jQuery plugin today and I'm having issues with getting a list of markers.
As long as I add all the markers manually (with addMarker or addMarkers) all works well and the:

```
.gmap3({action:'get', name:'marker', all:true});
```

gives proper list of markers.

However, if i use the action:getRoute and the addDirectionsRenderer - the markers are not 'gettable' by code pasted above.

My code for showing the directions is below - it works and shows them properly on the map. Only issue is that I cannot get any markers out of it, so I can process them after creation.

```
var optionDirections = {
        origin: startcoord,
        destination: stopcoord,
        waypoints: coordsAllGoogleStyle,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
....
.gmap3({
    action:'getRoute',
    options: optionDirections,
    callback: function(results) {
        if (!results) { alert('nodata'); return; }
        $(this).gmap3(
            {
                action:'addDirectionsRenderer',
                options:{
                    preserveViewport: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    directions:results
                }
            }
        );
        var res = $(this).gmap3({action:'get', name:'marker', all:true});
        alert('Found: '+res.length+' markers');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to make things simple, I contacted the author of this api and it kind of not support it anymore because "now people use angular"

nice is'nt it...